# No scumbag steve hat?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, winter-bash-2012, hat-request

I want to express my disappointment. There is no "Scumbag Steve" hat. Why? I will go to great lengths to receive this hat, and I am sure some other people will too. Make it happen.

ps: My name is Steve in real life.

Comment: Because Stack Exchange is not 9gag... It's easy to get confused sometimes, though...

Comment: given the amount of downvotes I guess I deserve the "scumbag "hat. Still a pinch of humor doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry, I'm going to [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) this one. Right now we only have *one* designer, the amazing and wonderful **Jin** who basically single-handedly made most of the imagery for Winter Bash (**balpha** helped out, as did **Emmett**). Given this literal resource restraint, we made as many hats as we could, as well as brainstormed fair ways of awarding these hats.

There are *lots and lots* of hats that didn't get made, including my personal favorite, The Aretha Hat:

[image: aretha]

If we do custom per-site hats next year, or if we just extend the base set of hats, we'll definitely consider adding the scumbag hat to the list. :)

Comment: Scumbag hat - Committed voting fraud / Became a help vampire / Asked a chameleon question.... No thanks...

Comment: @Lix Pretty much -- we also didn't want to encourage "bad" behaviors at all.

Comment: Loads of downvotes could fit...